# Cucumber does not work with @EnableIf annotation

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, enable-if

I want to enable cucumber tests with @EnableIf annotation, but it is not working even if i add `@EnabledIf("false")`

here is the code that i use :

```
@EnabledIf("false")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberRoot {

    private int port = 8080;

    protected String DEFAULT_URL = "http://localhost:" + port + "/";

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate template;
}
```

for other integration tests beside cucumber i am able to use @EnableIf annotation.

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

> 1.1. What is JUnit 5?
>
> Unlike previous versions of JUnit, JUnit 5 is composed of several different modules from three different sub-projects.
>
> JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage
>
> The JUnit Platform serves as a foundation for launching testing frameworks on the JVM. It also defines the TestEngine API for developing a testing framework that runs on the platform. Furthermore, the platform provides a Console Launcher to launch the platform from the command line and a JUnit 4 based Runner for running any TestEngine on the platform in a JUnit 4 based environment. First-class support for the JUnit Platform also exists in popular IDEs (see IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans, and Visual Studio Code) and build tools (see Gradle, Maven, and Ant).
>
> JUnit Jupiter is the combination of the new programming model and extension model for writing tests and extensions in JUnit 5. The Jupiter sub-project provides a TestEngine for running Jupiter based tests on the platform.
>
> JUnit Vintage provides a TestEngine for running JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 based tests on the platform.

And like JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage, Cucumber is a test engine on the JUnit Platform. The annotation you are using is JUnit Jupiter annotation and can only be understood by JUnit Jupiter. Neither JUnit Vintage nor Cucumber can understand it.

However Cucumber does support OpenTest4Js `TestAbortedException`. So you can use a before hook to stop a scenario before any step are executed. Either by throwing the exception directly or using `Assumptions` from JUnit Jupiter.

```java
    @Before
    public void before() {
        boolean condition = // decide if tests should abort
        if (condition)
            throw new TestAbortedException()
    }

   @Before
   public void before() {
       boolean condition = // decide if tests should abort
       Assumptions.assumeTrue(condition, "Condition not met");
   }
```